# iBooks folder permissions issue. I had access, now I don't have access. How can I regain access please?

Tags: macos, permissions

I want to locate my iBook files and copy them to Calibre. I found a solution here somewhere and have now lost it. It suggested using the Terminal command above which worked well. I tried to copy the data into a new folder and that's when things went wrong. I can no longer access the folder containing the pdf files that show in iBooks.

In very simple language, how can I reinstate my permissions?

```
dazed2022@dazeds-MacBook-2023 ~ % ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks zsh: 
permission denied: /Users/dazed2023/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks
```

Access was originally granted and I could see the pdf files for the books I have installed. When I tried to copy them into another folder (which was offered to me as an option) I seemed to get a folder within a folder within a folder but no books in any of them.

Trying to repeat the command failed with the permissions message shown.

I have looked at some of the answers here, and I am afraid I don't fully understand them enough to be brave enough to try in case I mess things up even more.

What have I tried?

In Terminal:

```
dazed2022@dazeds-MacBook-2023 ~ % ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks zsh:
permission denied: /Users/dazed2023/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks
```

Apparently, this should have restored permsions for me. It didn't.